# Meta-analysis for case-control studies, confounding factors

Tags: meta-analysis, odds-ratio, confounding, pooling

Is there a way to adjust the pooled summary effect size (odds ratio) for confounding factors while performing a meta-analysis in R studio?

I am performing a meta-analysis and I don't want to pool adjusted with unadjusted OR from included studies, so I am wondering if there is a way to adjust the summary OR if I extract raw data.

Comment: If you have only aggregate data and no access to adjusted OR/HR estimates, than in my opinion you can only try meta-regression.

Comment: ok thanks, I will try it out.